# How to print out a network in peersim?

Tags: software

[Peersim](http://peersim.sourceforge.net/) is a peer-to-peer network simulator.  I'm simply trying to get the program to print out the network (an edge list is fine).  Presumably this is possible, since there is an in-built [writeEdgeList](http://peersim.sourceforge.net/doc/peersim/graph/GraphIO.html#writeEdgeList%28peersim.graph.Graph,%20java.io.PrintStream%29) function.

I suspect there is an easy way to do this by modifying this line in the example: `include.control io degree`  (Section 5 in [tutorial 2](http://peersim.sourceforge.net/tutorial2/tutorial2.html)) which instead prints out a table that lists the number of nodes with certain degrees.  But I don't know what to change "degree" to.

> **Question**: How do I print out an edge list of a network in Peersim?

Comment: There is a discussion of whether this is on-topic (I think it is) here: http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/132/is-network-simulation-on-topic